# ParseFacebookUtils [V4-1.9.1] logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground invalid date

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

Calling logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground always return null user and invalid date error

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Invalid date
```

I'm using ParseFacebookUtils [V4-1.9.1]

here is my code

```
private void onLoginUserClicked ()
{
    final List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("user_status");
    permissions.add("user_friends");

    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(LoginActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Error: "+err);
            } else
            {
                if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                } else {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

nothing  up-normal i cannot overcome this point any help?

Comment: Is the date on your device correctly set?

Comment: @nmortada Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @SubinSebastian I created new application and worked but still didn't know why this error occurred ! although same code and same configuration!

Comment: @nmortada Many things could go wrong. Anyway, I tried to setup an app with latest SDKs and I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I thought the only permissions you could request for read permissions were public_profile, email, and user_friends. If you want more you have to have the app reviewed by facebook. I don't think user_status is one of them. I haven't tested to see if that's the problem though. Link here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 2):

I had simular issue.

I missed this methode:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```